# How to do a transient simulation using LTspice?

Tags: transistors, ltspice

I have the following circut that resembles a CMOS inverter. Now I want to do a transient simulation on this circut but I am not sure how to do it.
I always get a straight line! Not sure why. I tried everything.
In this transistor I have VOH=5V, VOL=0V
I tried changing the voltage in the advanced settings and to put pulse but I didn't undertand how to set the values?
Any help?

[image]

Comment: Press `F1`, and start reading from the beginning. Get to know the tool you are using. This is a most basic question about the usage.

Comment: i did do a transient simulation before , but i did it on a voltage that was a step function , but now since the voltage v2 is continues i don't know what to do ..

Comment: because this is circuet v2 always changes from 0 to 5 i don't understand what values to insert on the voltage advanced settings

Comment: Do you want to make V2 a square wave so you can see the output (across C1)?

Comment: It sounds like you don't know what a transient simulation is, or how to setup a simple source. You cannot go further without understanding some basic things. It is a good idea now to stop and look for tutorials on SPICE analysis.

Comment: it is not a square wave ,, if you connect more than one inverter then the output of one invertor is the input to another one

Comment: I don't think Spice is the problem.

Comment: concerd citizen , i did search about spice analysis but they always use a step input voltage or square voltage

Comment: yes i know i just don't understand how to insert the values of such a voltage current

Comment: becuase it is supposed to be continues right ?

Comment: i plotted the output voltage according to v2 using dc sweep .. where i inserted v2 to be from 0 to 5 , but when i try to do transient analysis i don't have the option to do this ..

Comment: i get a straight line :/

Answer (score 2):

You have no time-varying signals so you will get a straight line. LTspice calculates the initial operating point and nothing in your circuit changes from there.

Add a step input or an AC input and you'll see something. Right click on your voltage source V2 and select advanced and make it time-varying.

You can tell it to skip the initial operating point solution in the Edit Simulation Command dialog and set initial conditions using .ic directives but that is more complex and may not give you what you want.